# Button onClick not firing

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have textbox with onTextChanged event and postback is true. Now when I change some text and click on button, only the onTextchanged event is triggered. Button's OnClick event is ignored. I have to click second time to fire OnClick. Can I fire both on with click of button ?

Thank you

Comment: You're doing an auto-postback when the text changes?  Don't... do that.  Seriously, that's an *awful* UX.  As for why this is happening, I suspect the postback is already being triggered when the text changes and you're only coincidentally clicking the button while the page is waiting for a response for a moment.  The postback only contains the text changed event since that's all that triggered it.  If you want the user to have to click a button instead, remove the auto-postback on the text changed event.

Comment: @David - depending on the scenario, I'm pretty sure there are circumstances that make a textbox with auto-postback appropriate.

Comment: I could not avoid auto-postback on textbox, other fields in the form depend on the value in it.

Comment: Depending on how you've coded, I think you can actually use javascript on Text changed, that triggers button click.

Comment: @NETRookie You most certainly can. This is way better then auto postback for text changes (A server call for every character is absolute brutal). Assumption: what is the text for, is it just for a submit form? If so it would make sense not to watch the textbox change at all, but then again this is just an assumption as you provide no purpose.